# How to switch layers[] in esri leaflet dynamiclayer

Tags: javascript, web-services, leaflet, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I have a single MapService with multiple layers. I'd like to utilize layer group for changing layers with radio buttons, but want to use it with the [layers[] array option](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html) rather that creating a single L.esri.dynamicMapLayer etc... for each layer.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
  var msndfd = "https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nowcoast/forecast_meteoceanhydro_sfc_ndfd_time/MapServer";

            var minTemp = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
                url: msndfd,
                layers: [8],
                opacity: .7
            });
```

How do we switch layers based on that layers array # such as [4,8,12,16] while using the L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps)? So each of the overlayMaps would essentially be a layer# not another dynamicMapLayer variable such as minTemp in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

the way Leaflet's layers control is currently written is to add/remove layers from the map in reaction to user interaction with the checkboxes and radio buttons.

if you'd like to organize things so that choosing a different radio ensures that `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer.setLayers()` is called instead, you'd have to customize the control to lay out its UI differently (referencing a single base layer and an array of sublayers to toggle) and ensure that the appropriate action occurs when a new radio is selected.

existing logic for laying out the list - 
[Control.Layers.js#L313-L322](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/013198c9e2fa3b344ea8f093c932eae50fe236b7/src/control/Control.Layers.js#L313-L322)

existing logic for responding to user interaction - 
[Control.Layers.js#L382-L387](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/013198c9e2fa3b344ea8f093c932eae50fe236b7/src/control/Control.Layers.js#L382-L387)

my gut reaction is that you'd probably be better off accepting how the control is already designed, but i'm sure you have your reasons.